# New MacBook Pro Retina, bad battery?

Tags: battery, macbook-pro

I just purchased a brand-new MacBook Pro, Retina (15" screen). The "Hello" pamphlet in the box starts out:

> Your battery is charged and ready to go, so you can start using your Mac right out of the box.

However, the battery was completely drained. It charged up fairly quickly (I didn't time that, however) and the device functions fine.

I used it off and on for a total of around 40-45 minutes this morning -- usual web surfing with maybe 2-3 minutes of video, max. This took the power level down from about 94% to 75%. Then I closed the lid to see how the battery would hold up while the device slept. After 8 hours away at my office, I came back to find it at 70% (down from 75%).

**Question** Should the lack of charge out of the box be reason enough to return this thing? And is the draw-down on power I described indicative of the normal, expected battery performance?

Comment: Give it some time, like 2 or 3 loadcycles then come back to us if it still the same

Comment: Try using [Coconut Battery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) to get data about the health of your battery. It will tell you the charge design capacity versus your current battery. It will also tell you how many charge cycles the battery has seen. A new system should be near design capacity and very low cycles. You can get this from "System Information" too, but I find CoconutBattery more convenient plus it can save a report history.

Comment: You have all you need already on your mac. Open the About this mac- more info -sys report, look for Battery information in system report. 3d party stuff does not know more then your mac already does. It will tell you the health of your battery. Full Charge Capacity (mAh): Charging cycles count ect... Hold the ALT key and click on the batter Icon to see who is using most power. In the Utility folder -Activity window there is a lot of information about energy and consumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best is to use Apple tools already on your Mac to check your battery.

Open Activity in utility folder- and look under the the Energy tab.

[image: battery]

Next, open About this Mac- More- sys report:

Look for battery information there.

It should show something like:

- Fully charged capacity (>6500 mah), --that is a good indicator how "old" is the battery, the older they get the lower is the Fully Charged capacity number.
- Look at the charge cycles (<5)- a good indicator how many times the battery was charged, with normal life been 1000 Cycles (or 3-5 years)